# XMLHttpRequest:variable'effect in function

Tags: javascript, ajax

What effect does the variable `XMLHttpReqeust` have in the following codes:

```
function getHTTPObject() {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined") {
        XMLHttpRequest = function () {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');
            } catch (e) {

            }
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
            } catch (e) {

            }
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch (e) {

            }
            return false;
        }
     }
     return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

I have tried to remove the variable `XMLHttpReqeust` and the code working normally. Does it just commonly create an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Purpose of your function**

> It is just checking to see if the symbol XMLHttpRequest is defined in
>   the browser or not as a means of seeing whether this browser natively
>   supports Ajax calls or not.

Moreover I would suggest to remove this code, unless you have some extremely odd requirement to support IE6, As It is no longer needed.

As an example:

```
var x = 3;

console.log(typeof x);    // "number"
console.log(typeof y);    // "undefined"

// And, in any modern browser
console.log(typeof XMLHttpRequest);  // "function"

// In IE6
console.log(typeof XMLHttpRequest);  // "undefined"
```

This type of check for the presence of **XMLHttpRequest** is for **very old Microsoft browsers (IE6 and older)** and is **no longer needed** and can be **safely** removed.

---

**What your function is doing actually**

This function is **always** creating a **new `XMLHttpRequest()`** object.

As your **if condition** `if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined")` will always return `false`

So this line is executed everytime you call this fucntion

> `return new XMLHttpRequest();`

and it will create a **XMLHttpRequest** instance everytime.

---

**What is XMLHttpRequest ?**

> **The XMLHttpRequest object is used to exchange data with a server
>   behind the scenes.** It can Update a web page without reloading the page. It Requests data from a server after the page has loaded and Receives data from a server after the page has loaded.

In simple words it is used to make an **AJAX** call to the server. You can learn more about **XMLHttpRequest** [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp)

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Are you quoting something in all those yellow boxes?  If so, you should provide attribution.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a polyfill that adds XMLHttpRequest support to old versions of Internet Explorer.  Old versions of IE use a proprietary ActiveX interface instead of the standard XMLHttpRequest API.

IE 7 and up support the standard XMLHttpRequest object.  You should be able to do away with this code unless you have to support IE 6 or under.